# Drag and Drop Files into a Listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

i am creating my first mvvm app in wpf, i came to a point where i need to drag and drop files into  a ListBox, i couldn't see any other way to do it but use the DragEnter and the Drop events, then add the dropped files to my collection by casting the DataContext of the view to my ViewModel and the accessing the collection from there, and that is working really great.

something like this in my View in the drop event

```
 (this.DataContext as ImageViewModel).ToUpload.Add(new ImageModel() { localfilelocation = fi.FullName })
```

but is there anyother way do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be honest, dragging and dropping is probably one of those activities that MVVM finds most difficult to fit naturally into it's paradigm. However, the most common way of doing this is by using **Attached Behaviours**. A `DragDropBehaviour`, sub-classing `Behavior<T>` will allow you to hook into those events on the `ListBox` and have the advantage of being totally re-usable.

A good example of this can be found [here](http://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/06/26/wpf-itemscontrol-drag-drop-behavior/).

Comment: +1 for "To be honest, dragging and dropping is probably one of those activities that MVVM finds most difficult to fit naturally into it's paradigm."

Comment: Thats exactly what i looking for, something reuseable i didn't know that such things exist thanks for that example

Comment: Those who don't use Expression Blend can get the class libraries required for *Behavior<T>* from nuget under the package name: [System.Windows.Interactivity v4.0 for WPF](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF/2.0.20525)